# C# - How to Align Dynamically Created Label and Textbox Beside Each Other

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So far I have dynamically created labels and textbox that are created from this function in C#

```
private void AddControls(int controlNumber, string label)
{
    var newLabel = new Label() 
    {
        Text = "(" + label + ")"
    };
    var title = new Label()
    {
        Text = "External Name",
    };
    var newTextbox = new TextBox()
    {
        Width = 306,
        MaxLength = 10
    };

    // textbox needs a unique id to maintain state information
    newTextbox.ID = "TextBox_" + controlNumber;

    // add the labels and textbox to form
    Name.Controls.Add(title);
    Name.Controls.Add(newTextbox);
    Name.Controls.Add(newLabel);
    Name.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
}
```

The dynamic part is working fine except I want the title and newTextBox to be side by side with the newLabel below. Also, Name is the only id that the labels and text boxes can be added to. Can't seem to figure out how to do this within C# and NOT HTML. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Aligning Dynamically Created Textboxes Side-By-Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315388/c-sharp-aligning-dynamically-created-textboxes-side-by-side)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anybody that has the same problem I figured it out. I added this to the end so that the title and textbox stay on the same line with the label underneath

```
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(title);
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(newTextbox);
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(newLabel);
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        df_External_Name.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the location on the form using the `Location` property on the controls.  This takes a `Point` as it's value

```
newLabel.Location = new Point(10, 50);
newTextbox.Location = new Point(80, 50);
```

This will set their co-ordinates on the form.  You will need to check the size of the controls to get them to line up vertically, but the above will put them on the same horizontal line.

I imagine `Name` is the name of the form that this function resides within? you will most likely need to pass a reference of the Form instance you wish the controls to appear on if you wish them to appear on another form.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solution except System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label does not contain a definition for Location.  Also, Name is the HtmlCellTable that the textbox and label are being applied to. Do you have any other solutions?